# getMapPostition returns null value

Tags: java, jmapviewer

```
Point da = map1().getMapPosition(48.922499263758255, 16.875);
System.out.println(da);
```

Can someone help me? I want to convert a coordinate to a point by using this `getMapPosition`, but whatever I do it gives me a `null` value. Why is it happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check of the relevant [`JMapViewer`](https://sourceforge.net/p/jmapviewer/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/JMapViewer/src/main/java/org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/JMapViewer.java) source shows that your call to `getMapPosition()` invokes a nearby overload with `checkOutside` set to `true`. The result is `null` if the `Point` corresponding to the coordinates is outside the visible map.

```
if (checkOutside && (p.x < 0 || p.y < 0 || p.x > getWidth() || p.y > getHeight())) {
    return null;
}
```

Instead, use one of the implementations that lets you set `checkOutside` to `false` explicitly. For example,

```
Point da = map1().getMapPosition(48.9225, 16.875, false);
```

or

```
Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(48.9225, 16.875);
Point da = map1().getMapPosition(coord, false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your reply, I figured out where I am wrong, I just needed to create a variable Coordinate coord then add the false

     Point da = map1().getMapPosition(coord, false);

then it gives me now the correct Point values tnx a lot :)